# django 1.7 migrations: changes detected while nothing has changed

Tags: django, django-1.7, django-migrations

How are changes detected by the `makemigrations` command in django 1.7?

I have the issue that it always tells me there are changes for one of my field whereas there are not. When I run the command, it just writes the same migration file over and over with no changes.

The field is a custom field on which I implemented the deconstruct method and have some parameters that are objects so I used the deconstructible decorator.

I created a project on github that replicates the issue: https://github.com/YAmikep/django-testmigrations

What did I do wrong? Is this a bug?

Here is what I ran:

```
/projects/testmigrations$ python manage.py makemigrations app1
Migrations for 'app1':
  0001_initial.py:
    - Create model ModelA
/projects/testmigrations$ python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, contenttypes, auth, app1, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying app1.0001_initial... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
/projects/testmigrations$ python manage.py makemigrations
Migrations for 'app1':
  0002_auto_20141014_2123.py:
    - Alter field field1 on modela
/projects/testmigrations$ python manage.py makemigrations
Migrations for 'app1':
  0003_auto_20141014_2123.py:
    - Alter field field1 on modela
```

The migration files 0002_auto_20141014_2123.py and 0003_auto_20141014_2123.py contain the exact same operations:

```
operations = [
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='modela',
        name='field1',
        field=app1.models.CustomField(max_length=50, value_manager=app1.models.ValueManager(values=[app1.models.Value(val=1), app1.models.Value(val=2)])),
    ),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be the same as in https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23473

The solution is to add a `__eq__` method on the classes marked as deconstructible.